# iPhone: Need some facebook for IOS development rules

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an IOS app for some extra facebook features that API's can provide, but couldnt't find the "rules", so dont want my app rejected by either Appstore or FB, so I want to know all policies in advance.

for example:

-Can I sell this app in AppStore?

-Am I free to use all functionality that FB API's provides how ever i want? or there are some things "I should and should not do"?

-It does not allow me to name my app anything includes text "Facebook", but I see in apple store there are apps with name Facebook text by other companies, how is that possible? (e.g. Myphone+ for facebook)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does not ask for any commission (as you don't make any money just offer an interface from your app to access Facebook services). They have an open source [iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), with reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/), which does all the authentication/authorization work. You can find the general documentation for developing Facebook stuff on mobile [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). Depending on which services you want to access you will have to ask the user for Facebook [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) through the SDK. Apple have never, to my knowledge refused an app because of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: tnx, sorry but I can not make money with an app using Facebook services? you mean I have to make the apps free in app store?

Comment: no, doesn't matter if they are not free, you can use the facebook SDK all the same.